# Prove that $x \mapsto (f_1 (x), \ldots, f_m(x))$ is differentiable at $x$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I'm doing this exercise about the derivative. Could you please verify if my proof looks fine or contains logical gaps/errors? Thank you so much for your help!

> Assume that  $f_j:X \to E_j$ is differentiable at $x \in X$ for all $j = \overline{1,m}$. Prove that $$\begin
> {array}{l|rcl}
> F & X
>  & \longrightarrow & E_{1} \times \cdots \times E_{m} \\
>     & x & \longmapsto & (f_1 (x), \ldots, f_m(x)) \end{array}$$ is differentiable at $x$.

**My attempt:**

Consider the map $$\begin
{array}{l|rcl}
A_x & X
 & \longrightarrow & E_{1} \times \cdots \times E_{m} \\
    & h & \longmapsto & (f'_1 (x)(h), \ldots, f'_m(x)(h)) \end{array}$$

For $h,h' \in X$ and $\lambda \in \mathbb K$, we have $$\begin{aligned} A_x (h+\lambda h') &= (f'_1 (x)(h+\lambda h'), \ldots, f'_m(x)(h+\lambda h')) \\ &= (f'_1 (x)(h), \ldots, f'_m(x)(h)) + (\lambda f'_1 (x)(h'), \ldots, \lambda f'_m(x)(h')) \\ &= (f'_1 (x)(h), \ldots, f'_m(x)(h)) + \lambda( f'_1 (x)(h'), \ldots, f'_m(x)(h')) \\ &= A_x(h)+\lambda A_x(h')\end{aligned}$$

Hence $A_x$ is linear. Moreover, each component of $A_x$ is continuous, so is $A_x$. As such, $A_x \in \mathcal L(X, E_{1} \times \cdots \times E_{m})$. We have $$\begin{aligned} &\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{F(x+h) - F(x) -A_x(h)}{\|h\|}\\ = &\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{(f_1 (x+h), \ldots, f_m(x+h)) - (f_1 (x), \ldots, f_m(x)) -(f'_1 (x)(h), \ldots, f'_m(x)(h))}{\|h\|} \\ =&\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{(f_1 (x+h)-f_1(x)-f_1'(x)(h),\ldots, f_m (x+h)-f_m(x)-f_m'(x)(h))}{\|h\|} \\ =&\lim_{h \to 0}  \left ( \frac{f_1 (x+h)-f_1(x)-f_1'(x)(h)}{\|h\|}, \ldots,\frac{f_m (x+h)-f_m(x)-f_1'(x)(h)}{\|h\|}  \right) \\ = &\left( \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f_1 (x+h)-f_1(x)-f_1'(x)(h)}{\|h\|}, \ldots, \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f_m(x+h)-f_1(x) -f_m'(x)(h)}{\|h\|}  \right) \\ =& \left(0, \ldots, 0 \right) \end{aligned}$$

As such, $F'(x) = A_x$.

Comment: It's quite fine for me.

Comment: looks completely logical for me